# Can't pass a function as parameter from a NextJS component

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have this type of code in a NextJS component:

```js
    const [currentGPS, setCurrentGPS] =
            useState({coords:{latitude:0.0,longitude:0.0}})

    useEffect(() => {
      utl.getGPSLocation(
        (v:{coords: {latitude:number; longitude:number;};})=>
        setCurrentGPS(v))
    }, [])
```

When using the function below:

```js
    function getGPSLocation({callBackFn}:
      {callBackFn:
        (v:{coords: {latitude:number; longitude:number;};}) => void
      }) {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position: {coords: {latitude:number; longitude:number;};}) => {
            callBackFn(position)
            console.log('(U)position.coords.latitude='+JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude))
            console.log('(U)position.coords.longitude='+JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude))
          });
      } else {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
    } /* End of getGPSLocation */
```

I get this error in the Web Developer Tools console of my web browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function
> NextJS 10
> page-1aeb39b39d44f814.js:1:332

The message above is due to the line of code:

```js
    callBackFn(position)
```

If I comment out the line, I see what I expect:

> (U)position.coords.latitude=25.515932844138406 page-2bc533c4f68ab71b.js:1:339
> (U)position.coords.longitude=67.32855152591916 page-2bc533c4f68ab71b.js:1:417

​Why am I getting the error? And what is the way to solve it?

I need help passing `setCurrentGPS`(as a callback) to `getGPSLocation`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getGPSLocation` is expecting an object with `callBackFn` key as argument. You can update your `useEffect` as following

```js
useEffect(() => {
  utl.getGPSLocation({
    callBackFn: (v: { coords: { latitude: number; longitude: number } }) =>
      setCurrentGPS(v)
  });
}, []);
```

**Or**, you can change the function definition

```js
function getGPSLocation(
  callBackFn: (v: { coords: { latitude: number; longitude: number } }) => void
) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position: { coords: { latitude: number; longitude: number } }) => {
        callBackFn(position);
        console.log('(U)position.coords.latitude=' + JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude));
        console.log('(U)position.coords.longitude=' + JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude));
      });
  } else {
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, both of your solutions work. Thanks a lot !